# Get Audio from PC microphone with a C# program

Tags: c#, audio, microphone

I need to capture audio from a PC with Windows 7 with a C# program. I need to get all the frequencies until 20 khz. Do you know if there are a way to do it?

Comment: I'd start buying a mike capable of "hearing" up to 20kHz, then google "c# record audio"

Answer (score 4):

Just try to use winmm.dll api function. Here is simple example.

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;

    namespace MicrophoneTest
    {
        class Program
        {

            [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
            private static extern int mciSendString(string MciComando, string MciRetorno, int MciRetornoLeng, int CallBack);

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //create Test alias
                mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias Test", null, 0, 0);

                //start
                mciSendString("record Test", null, 0, 0);

                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                //pause
                mciSendString("pause Test", null, 0, 0);

                //save
                mciSendString("save Test " + "test.wav", null, 0, 0);
                mciSendString("close Test", null, 0, 0);

                //press any key
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Function signature [MSDN: mciSendString function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161(v=vs.85).aspx).

List of commands [MSDN: Command Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797790(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at the NAudio Library at GitHub https://github.com/naudio/NAudio.

A nice project for recording mic input with NAudio can be found here http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 2):

I found some links that could help you

Visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2615/DirectShow-NET?
Or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4889/A-full-duplex-audio-player-in-C-using-the-waveIn-w?

Or You could use Matalab and Link it with .Net using Liydos dlls