# integrating voice chat api(http://voicechatapi.com/) into a vb.net desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, voip, voice

I have a application I am making that does a bunch of things but I wanted to integrate voice chat rooms into it.After looking around for a bit I found [voicechatapi](http://voicechatapi.com/) it seemed pretty cool that they offered it for free to use. So i was thinking of how to integrate that into a desktop app without opening webpage for a user of the application. The API docs say that you can send a post request to http://voicechatapi.com/api/v1/conference/ and it returns a json formatted data object.

I used this in my app

```
Using client As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim result As String = client.UploadString("http://voicechatapi.com/api/v1/conference/", "")
            Dim deserializedResult As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(result)
            'Dim browser As New VoiceChatWebControl()
            'browser.Show()
            'browser.Navigate(deserializedResult("conference_url").ToString)
        End Using
```

which indeed returns the code block which I put into a dictionary.  In the commented out code I attempted to open it up in a control that inherits the webBrowser Control

```
Public Class VoiceChatWebControl
Inherits WebBrowser
End Class
```

but I dont know how to handle the microphone access and the other things that happens I.e when a user closes the that room/wants to mute their microphone and other thins without opening up a actual webbrowser window to do all of this. instead I want to make individual buttons for all of that but my biggest problem right now is how to open up the website and have it access the users microphone to use the chat room without opening up a visible web browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893674/get-audio-from-pc-microphone-with-a-c-sharp-program

Comment: thanks but im not looking to capture the stream or anything. Im looking for a way to have the audio conference website capture audio through my app but have it so the user doesn't see the website.they only see the ui that i make for them